# How can i add to dataGridView1 a data to the last row/column?

Tags: c#, winforms

In top of form1 i did:

```
private System.Timers.Timer _refreshTimer;
private int _thisProcess;
```

Then in the Form1 Load event:

```
_thisProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
InitializeRefreshTimer();
PopulateApplications();
```

Then the timer init method:

```
void InitializeRefreshTimer()
        {
            _refreshTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);
            _refreshTimer.SynchronizingObject = this;
            _refreshTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(TimerToUpdate_Elapsed);
            _refreshTimer.Start();
        }
```

Then the timer elapsed event:

```
void TimerToUpdate_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            PopulateApplications();
        }
```

In the end the Populate method:

```
void PopulateApplications()
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
            foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses("."))
            {
                if (p.Id != _thisProcess)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (p.MainWindowTitle.Length > 0)
                        {
                            String status = p.Responding ? "Running" : "Not Responding";
                            dataGridView1.Rows.Add( p.MainWindowTitle, status);
                        }
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
            }
        }
```

The variable status show in the column2 but let's say i want that status will be display for each process/app in column5 ? How can i move it ?

This is an image showing what i get whne running the program:

[image]

This is the method im using:

```
void PopulateApplications()
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();

            DataGridViewImageColumn img = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
            img.HeaderText = "Icon";
            img.Name = "ImageCol";
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(img);
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("AppName", "Application Name");
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Status", "Status");
            foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
            {
                if (p.MainWindowTitle.Length > 1)
                {
                    var icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(p.MainModule.FileName);
                    Image ima = icon.ToBitmap();
                    (dataGridView1.Columns["ImageCol"] as DataGridViewImageColumn).Image = ima;
                    String status = p.Responding ? "Running" : "Not Responding";
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(icon, p.MainWindowTitle, status);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Great. And about the icon thing, I think you could get it this way `var icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(p.MainModule.FileName);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this code?

```
void PopulateApplications()
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();

    DataGridViewImageColumn img = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
    img.HeaderText = "Icon";
    img.Name = "ImageCol";
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(img);
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add("AppName", "Application Name");
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Status", "Status");
    foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
    {
        if (p.MainWindowTitle.Length > 1)
        {
            var icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(p.MainModule.FileName);
            Image ima = icon.ToBitmap();
            String status = p.Responding ? "Running" : "Not Responding";
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(ima, p.MainWindowTitle, status);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Anuraj im getting null exception on this line: (dataGridView1.Columns[0] as DataGridViewImageColumn).Image = ima;

Comment: You have anything else in your gridview?

Comment: Anuraj im getting exception now on a different line: var icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(p.MainModule.FileName); the exception is: A 32 bit processes cannot access modules of a 64 bit process

Comment: Added to the question the exception full message.

Comment: What is your platform target? it is AnyCPU or x86?

Comment: Anuraj i changed now my project ot AnyCpu and the exception is gone but now i see when the program is running on column1 in all the cells the word: (Icon) and not the icon image it self.

Comment: Anuraj i see now that in Column1 instead see the icons i see (Icon) and in column9 and after i see icon of skype in all the cells same icon of skype only and in column after 9 i see all the cells with red x in it.

Comment: Anuraj what it does is adding keep adding all the time columns to the right end with icons and red x in all cells. In column1 there is only the word (Icon) in all the cells. What i wnated is to add once to the first column1 near each process/app it's icon.

Comment: Are you using my code? if you are I am adding the columns only first time. Then I am adding rows only. Before `foreach` statement I am adding /creating the columns. `dataGridView1.Rows.Add(icon, p.MainWindowTitle, status);` statement adds the rows.

Comment: Anuraj i saw it im using your code but since im updating it every 5 seconds with a timer maybe that cause it adding the columns to the right each time. And i need to update it with the timer. Second i will upload an image to my question showing what i see when running the program.

Comment: Anuraj updated my question i dragged the columns to the left so you can see the column after number 9. I have only 9 columns but it keep adding with the timer more columns and icons i the right and red x's . In the first column all i see is (Icon).